# Visual Studio - Windows Form - CheckedListBox not inserting correctly. C#

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am working on a Windows Form that has a CheckedListBox control (cbIntendedMajor) that I am attempting to insert into an Access database. I am not returning any errors, however when I select more than one check box item only the first one selected inserts into the table with a comma. Any pointers on what I am missing here? Below is my code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\Interest.accdb";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        string text = "INSERT INTO InterestCard (FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, City, State, ZipCode, Phone, Email, DOB, Gender, HighSchool, GraduationYear, PlannedTerm, IntendedMajor) VALUES (@FName, @LName, @SAddress, @City, @State, @Zip, @Phone, @Email, @DOB, @Gender, @HSchool, @GradYear, @PTerm, @IMajor)";
        cmd.CommandText = text;

            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txtFirstName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", txtLastName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SAddress", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", txtState.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZipCode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dtpDOB.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", rbFemale.Checked);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HSchool", txtHighSchool.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradYear", txtGraduationYear.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PTerm", txtTermofEnrollment.Text);




            foreach (string s in cbIntendedMajor.CheckedItems)
            {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMajor", s + ",");

            }


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
```

Comment: You repeatedly call AddWithValue("@IMajor"), only the last one will have an effect.  Create the string first, *then* call AddWithValue.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't even notice that I was adding within the loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your parameter can only be added once. You might consider instead, iterating over the .CheckedItems, creating a single string with each item added with a comma. Then outside of the foreach() loop you can cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@IMajor", fullString